# Vagrant and Docker provider: a way to force proxy VM for Linux hosts?

Tags: linux, docker, vagrant, dockerfile

TL&DR: **Is there a way to force a proxy VM to be used by Vagrant, even if the host OS supports Docker natively?**

I'm using Vagrant with Docker provider. The Vagrant VM is the OS and Docker containers host my apps (web servers, DBs).

Problem:

> Linux containers do not run natively on non-Linux machines. If your
>   developers are on Mac or Windows, they can't run Docker containers
>   natively. Vagrant detects these cases and **automatically spins up a
>   Linux virtual machine** to run the Docker containers.
>
> [...]
>
> If Vagrant is being used with Docker on Linux, **Vagrant won't
>   automatically spin up a virtual machine** and instead will **run Docker
>   natively**

*Source: http://www.vagrantup.com/blog/feature-preview-vagrant-1-6-docker-dev-environments.html*

It's great that Vagrant automatically spin up a proxy VM for OS that doesn't support natively Docker, because they so have the same OS to work with.
But for Linux hosts, we're stuck with native Docker installation, which cause few problems:

- file/folder permission
- different user for different Linux OS (Apache user is sometime "apache", sometime "www", depending of your Linux distro)

---

Here is my Vagrant files for references:

**DockerHost.Vagrantfile**

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.provision "docker"
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.vm.define "dockerhost"

  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8080
  config.vm.synced_folder "/sites", "/sites" [...]

  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    vb.name = "Vagrant-Dockerhost"
    vb.memory = 1024 # => Required by MySQL Server
  end

end
```

**Vagrantfile**

```
ENV['VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER'] = 'docker'
DOCKER_HOST_NAME = "dockerhost"
DOCKER_HOST_VAGRANTFILE = "DockerHost.Vagrantfile"

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.define "mysql-server" do |v|
    v.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
      d.image = "mysql"
      d.name = "mysql-server"
      d.env = {
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "rootpasswd",
        MYSQL_USER: "mysqluser",
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: "userpasswd",
        MYSQL_DATABASE: "dev"
      }
      d.volumes = ["/mysql:/var/lib/mysql"]
      d.cmd = ["/entrypoint.sh", "mysqld"]
      d.remains_running = true
      d.vagrant_machine = "#{DOCKER_HOST_NAME}"
      d.vagrant_vagrantfile = "#{DOCKER_HOST_VAGRANTFILE}"
    end
  end

  config.vm.define "apache-server" do |v|
    v.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
      d.image = "lacavalerie/apache-server"
      d.ports = ["80:80"]
      d.name = "apache-server"
      d.link("mysql-server:db")
      d.volumes = [...]
      d.cmd = ["/scripts/setup.rb"]
      d.remains_running = true
      d.vagrant_machine = "#{DOCKER_HOST_NAME}"
      d.vagrant_vagrantfile = "#{DOCKER_HOST_VAGRANTFILE}"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `d.force_host_vm = true` option

From Vagrant docs:

> **force_host_vm (boolean)** - If true, then a host VM will be spun up even
>   if the computer running Vagrant supports Linux containers. This is
>   useful to enforce a consistent environment to run Docker. This value
>   defaults to "true" on Mac and Windows hosts and defaults to "false" on
>   Linux hosts. Mac/Windows users who choose to use a different Docker
>   provider or opt-in to the native Docker builds can explicitly set this
>   value to false to disable the behavior.